# How to open a EVERNOTE file extension "*.exb"?

Tags: database, file, system-databases

I have evernote.com  app running on my machine ----

they store the notes in my local machine unbder a database with extension  "*.exb"

How can I open that database file with that extension   .EXB?

Any help or any software that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Evernote for Windows keeps data in SQLite databases, so the SQLite viewer could be used to access them.